# Is there a quick way in VS2010 to force all winforms designer.cs autogenerated code to regenerate themselves in a c# project?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a lot of designer.cs files to regenerate. Usually I just make some trivial edit to each of them to force the designer code to regenerate. But is there a quicker way to make this happen to a bunch of designers en masse?

Comment: IIRC, all versions of VS have a "build" (partial build, as needed) and "rebuild" (full rebuild - refresh everything).  Doesn't "rebuild" work for you (i.e. rebuild all binaries)?  Q: Does simply closing the designer window and re-opening it (after a rebuild) fully refresh everything?

Comment: The designer will regenerate them when it needs to. Why else do you want them to be regenerated?

Comment: because the designer is setting properties on one of my classes that i don't want it to. I put an attribute on that property to hide it from the designer. So now i have to regenerate all my designers so all those lines where it tries to set that property are gone.

Comment: no a rebuild won't work. If it did, then I'd have a lot of designer.cs files to commit in tortoisesvn

Comment: oh wait, a rebuild then opening them makes them regenerate

Comment: Delete the .designer.cs files, open each of the .cs files.

Comment: @JohnSaunders, won't deleting the .Designer.cs file result in data loss, for example, property values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that you'll have compile first - a rebuild would probably work best - then open each of the Forms/Controls up in design view mode.

If you really want to make sure you get the cleanest regen, then you could delete all the .designer.cs files before opening up the design view. This might dramatically change the order of things in the designer file though.

Comment: this seems to be the best way to go. Luckily I have someone to this kind of work for me.